# Kafka Streams and RPC: is calling REST service in map() operator considered an anti-pattern?

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

The naive approach for implementing the use case of enriching an incoming stream of events stored in Kafka with reference data - is by calling in `map()` operator an external service REST API that provides this reference data, for each incoming event.

```
eventStream.map((key, event) -> /* query the external service here, then return the enriched event */)
```

Another approach is to have second events stream with reference data and store it in `KTable` that will be a lightweight embedded "database" then join main event stream with it.

```
KStream<String, Object> eventStream = builder.stream(..., "event-topic");
KTable<String, Object> referenceDataTable = builder.table(..., "reference-data-topic");
KTable<String, Object> enrichedEventStream = eventStream 
    .leftJoin(referenceDataTable , (event, referenceData) -> /* return the enriched event */)
    .map((key, enrichedEvent) -> new KeyValue<>(/* new key */, enrichedEvent)
    .to("enriched-event-topic", ...);
```

Can the "naive" approach be considered an anti-pattern? Can the "`KTable`" approach be recommended as the preferred one?

Kafka can easily manage millions of messages per minute. Service that is called from the `map()` operator should be capable of handling high load too and also highly-available. These are extra requirements for the service implementation. But if the service satisfies these criteria can the "naive" approach be used?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Yes, it is ok to do RPC inside Kafka Streams operations such as `map()` operation. You just need to be aware of the pros and cons of doing so, see below.  Also, you should do any such RPC calls *synchronously* from within your operations (I won't go into details here why; if needed, I'd suggest to create a new question).

**Pros of doing RPC calls from within Kafka Streams operations:**

- Your application will fit more easily into an existing architecture, e.g. one where the use of REST APIs and request/response paradigms is common place. This means that you can make more progress quickly for a first proof-of-concept or MVP.
- The approach is, in my experience, easier to understand for many developers (particularly those who are just starting out with Kafka) because they are familiar with doing RPC calls in this manner from their past projects. Think: it helps to move gradually from request-response architectures to event-driven architectures (powered by Kafka).
- Nothing prevents you from starting with RPC calls and request-response, and then later migrating to a more Kafka-idiomatic approach.

**Cons:**

1. You are coupling the availability, scalability, and latency/throughput of your Kafka Streams powered application to the availability, scalability, and latency/throughput of the RPC service(s) you are calling. This is relevant also for thinking about SLAs.
2. Related to the previous point, Kafka and Kafka Streams scale very well. If you are running at large scale, your Kafka Streams application might end up DDoS'ing your RPC service(s) because the latter probably can't scale as much as Kafka. You should be able to judge pretty easily whether or not this is a problem for you in practice.
3. An RPC call (like from within `map()`) is a side-effect and thus a black box for Kafka Streams. The processing guarantees of Kafka Streams do not extend to such side effects.

   - Example: Kafka Streams (by default) processes data based on event-time (= based on when an event happened in the real world), so you can easily re-process old data and still get back the same results as when the old data was still new.  But the RPC service you are calling during such reprocessing might return a different response than "back then". Ensuring the latter is your responsibility.
   - Example: In the case of failures, Kafka Streams will retry operations, and it will guarantee exactly-once processing (if enabled) even in such situations. But it can't guarantee, by itself, that an RPC call you are doing from within `map()` will be idempotent. Ensuring the latter is your responsibility.

**Alternatives**

In case you are wondering what other alternatives you have: If, for example, you are doing RPC calls for looking up data (e.g. for enriching an incoming stream of events with side/context information), you can address the downsides above by making the lookup data available in Kafka directly. If the lookup data is in MySQL, you can setup a Kafka connector to continuously ingest the MySQL data into a Kafka topic (think: CDC). In Kafka Streams, you can then read the lookup data into a `KTable` and perform the enrichment of your input stream via a stream-table join.

Comment: "...MySQL ... read the lookup data into a KTable..." What if lookup is made over a gigantic data storage (e. g. heavy load balanced Hbase instance)? Is there any alternative then?

Answer (score 7):

I suspect most of the advice you hear from the internet is along the lines of, "OMG, if this REST call takes 200ms, how wil I ever process 100,000 Kafka messages per second to keep up with my demand?"

Which is technically true: even if you scale your servers up for your REST service, if responses from this app routinely take 200ms - because it talks to a server 70ms away (speed of light is kinda slow, if that server is across the continent from you...) and the calling microservice takes 130ms even if you measure right at the source....

With kstreams the problem may be worse than it appears. Maybe you get 100,000 messages a second coming into your stream pipeline, but some kstream operator `flatMap`s and that operation in your app creates 2 messages for every one object... so now you really have 200,000 messages a second crashing through your REST server.

**BUT** maybe you're using Kstreams in an app that has 100 messages a second, or you can partition your data so that you get a message per partition maybe even just once a second. In that case, you might be fine.

Maybe your Kafka data just needs to go somewhere else: ie the end of the stream is back into a Good Ol' RDMS. In which case yes, there's some careful balancing there on the best way to deal with potentially "slow" systems, while making sure you don't DDOS yourself, while making sure you can work your way out of a backlog.

So is it an anti-pattern? Eh, probably, if your Kafka cluster is LinkedIn size. Does it matter for you? Depends on how many messages/second you need to drive, how fast your REST service really is, how efficiently it can scale (ie your new kstreams pipeline suddenly delivers 5x the normal traffic to it...)

Comment: Loading the data into a Kafka topic and doing a KStream-KTable join is recommended---however, doing the external call is not necessarily an anti-pattern. Beside performance consideration, the nice property of load the data into a KTable is decouple your application from the external system. If you do the REST call and the external system is down, how to you handle this? With the data loaded into the KTable, this question resolves naturally. Also, if you want to enable exactly-once processing, a REST call is a side effect and not covered by exactly-once, while the join is covered.